# How to convert Array to IEnuramble

Tags: asp.net-core

I have this code that attempts to set a cookie.
My current issue is that `resp.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie })` displays an error in visual studio:

> Cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.CookieHeaderValue[]'
> to
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Net.Http.Headers.CookieHeaderValue>'

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RegAsync()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage resp = new HttpResponseMessage();
            var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("session");
            resp.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });
    }
```

Comment: Try this `resp.Headers.AddCookies(Enumerable.Empty<CookieHeaderValue>().Append(cookie));`

Comment: @KunalMukherjee This is the error that I get when I try that: Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.CookieHeaderValue>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Net.Http.Headers.CookieHeaderValue>'

Comment: Is System.Net.Http; included on top ?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Amazon;
using Amazon.Runtime;
using Amazon.SimpleEmail;
using Amazon.SimpleEmail.Model;
using CCManagementAPI.Controllers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using NLog.LayoutRenderers;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try specifying the namespace explicitly:

```cs
var cookie = new System.Net.Http.Headers.CookieHeaderValue("session");
resp.Headers.AddCookies(new[] { cookie });
```

Answer (score 1):

CookieHeaderValue is defined in two different namespaces:

- Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers
- System.Net.Http.Headers

The solution for me was to remove

`using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;`

and add:

`using System.Net.Http.Headers;`

*I can see from your [comment reply to an answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62958466/how-to-convert-array-to-ienuramble/70427195#comment111335830_62958466), that you are in fact including `using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;` so I believe the solution I recommend here will resolve your problem.*

The actual issue is that the method you are using is defined as AddCookies(IEnumerable<**System.Net.Http.Header**.CookieHeaderValue> cookies) but when you include `using Microsoft.Net.Http.Header;` then CookieHeaderValue is defined as **Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers**.CookieHeaderValue, which does not fulfill the parameter type prescribed by the method definition. When you include `using System.Net.Http.Headers;` instead then it is defined as **System.Net.Http.Headers**.CookieHeaderValue which **does** fulfill the method's prescribed parameter type correctly.